# Definition of sequence notation...(A), (A>B), and (A) - (A>B)

Tags: traminer

Hopefully a quick one ....

Regarding the output from `seqefsub()` operations, please point me to a definition of the output notation.

To be more specific, the parentheses in e.g.

- `(A)` means what;
- the greater than sign in `(A>B)` means what;
- and the hyphen in `(A)-(A>B)` means what.

`Section 10` of the excellent [User Guide](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/TraMineR/doc/TraMineR-Users-Guide.pdf) has examples, but I may have missed an unambiguous definition statement somewhere.

To quote the example in `Section 10.2` of the guide, what is the conceptual difference between `(Parent)-(Parent>Left)` and just `(Parent>Left)`?

Thanks,

Dave

**Update after Gilbert's comment....**

In attempting to clarify what I perhaps missed on page 106 of the user guide, I think the explanation - or at least confirmation - that I was looking for was something along the lines of the following framework. Apologies for the possible clumsy wordiness.

The context here is when `seqefsub()` results appear in the console....

`(A)` this is the number of times state A appears as the **first state**, and not as any subsequent state. That is - it counts the number of times A appears in the first column. *I assume here that I haven't missed another configuration option that counts first and all subsequent states of this type. If there is please let me know.*

`(A>B)` this is the number of occurrences of an event (i.e. a change of state) from A to B. This count refers to events **anywhere** in the sequence. *I am suggesting this is slightly different therefore to the state count above, assuming I haven't inadvertently misrepresented things. I note that constraints can be set to output single or multiple occurences.*

`(A)-(A>B)` this counts the number of times state A occurs as a first state, and where the A to B event occurs anywhere in the sequence. This includes A to B events immediately after the first state, and can include intervening **other states** between the first state A and the event A to B.

I hope this helps, and I hope this is a correct set of statements (based on investigations later than my original question).

**2nd Update after Gilbert's comment requesting an example....**

For the real data set ... (where J and I take the place of A and B)

```
> data   
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
1   I  J  J  I  J  J  I  K  J   D   J
2   G  K  R  I  J  D  J  R  I   J   N
3   K  K  I  R  M  M  K  R  J   K   I
4   R  R  B  R  I  G  R  G  R   G   G
5   J  J  J  J  J  J  J  T  Z   J   Z
6   R  K  R  K  M  R  R  J  J   J   R
7   J  I  I  I  I  I  I  I  I   I   I
8   J  J  J  J  J  J  J  J  J   J   R
9   J  R  J  R  J  R  J  J  I   S   R
10  J  J  J  J  J  I  J  J  J   J   J
11  G  J  J  J  J  I  I  I  R   J   J
12  I  I  D  M  D  I  I  D  I   I   D
13  R  M  R  R  J  J  J  J  J   J   J
```

then

```
> dataseq <- seqdef(data)

> dataseqe <- seqecreate(dataseq)

> datasubseq <- seqefsub(dataseqe, pMinSupport = 0.05)

> datasubseq[1:10]
```

gives

```
    Subsequence   Support Count
1          (J) 0.3846154     5
2        (J>I) 0.3846154     5
3        (R>J) 0.3846154     5
4        (J>R) 0.3076923     4
5        (I>J) 0.2307692     3
6    (J)-(J>I) 0.2307692     3
7        (K>R) 0.2307692     3
8          (R) 0.2307692     3
9        (D>J) 0.1538462     2
10         (G) 0.1538462     2
```

So ....

1) the count of 5 J-states `(J)` applies only to the first column/occurrence, and not to any subsequent J-states. There is a total of 57 J-states.

2) the count of 5 J-state to I-state change events `(J>I)` is a total count (for this constraint option), whenever they occur.

3) the count of 3 J-state followed by J-state-to-I-state subsequences `(J)-(J>I)` are the counts of the events in row 7 (cols 1 & 2), row 9 (col 1, and cols 8 & 9 ) and lastly row 10 (col 1, and cols 5 & 6); the last two cases having intervening states and/or events between the `(J)` and the `(J>I)`.

Back then to the question - is this correct and expected behaviour, and a correct interpretation. If so, why are state counts done on a different basis to event/state change counts?

Comment: In case nobody here can answer, you can perhaps ask the question on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), where people with more R experience hang out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did originally add the R tag, but a nice reviewer suggested I remove that tag. Is the Traminer tag sufficient?

Comment: It would definitely be sufficient on CrossValidated. For StackOverflow... that's a meta.StackOverflow debate I don't really want to get into, so I'd just trust the reviewer until someone says otherwise ;)

Comment: The explanation is given top page 106 of the user's guide. `A` is an event, and `A>B` is another event. `Parent>Left` is the label given in the example to the transition from state `Parent` to state `Left Home`. Event `Parent` is 'living with parents at start of sequence'.

Comment: @Gilbert - I have tried to be clearer by updating the question, by adding what I think is happening. Thx!

Comment: @BigOldDave The labels `A`, `A>B`, ... are defined by the user, or automatically if you use a state to event transformation method. So, you should provide a minimal working example where we see where the labels come from. In my previous comment, I referred to the example in the user's guide where `Parent` is defined as 'living with parents at start of the sequence' by the default `tevent="transition"` method used by `seqecreate` to transform the state sequences into event sequences. So here `Parent` can only occur at the first place by definition.

Comment: @Gilbert - great answer! Cannot upvote yet, as my rep is currently too low.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example the event sequences are derived from the state sequence object `dataseq` with
`seqecreate(dataseq)`. Since you don't provide the `tevent` argument, the default `tevent =  "transition"` is used (see `help(seqecreate)`). With this value, the events are defined as the transitions from a state `A` to a state `B` and are labeled `A>B`. In addition, a specific event labeled `A` is associated to the sequence start to indicate the state at the beginning of the sequence. So, although the same symbol is used, `A` in event sequences is an event---the start event---and should not be confused with the `A` in state sequences where it is a state.

The above is specific to the `tevent="transition"` option. For instance, with `tevent="state"`, the events would be the start of the spells and labeled as `A` to indicate the start of a spell in state `A`. In that case the event `A` could occur anywhere in the sequence, not only at the start.

Now about the parentheses. They indicate the transitions (or transactions), a transition being defined as the set of simultaneous events that provoke the state change. For example:

`(a,b)` indicates that two events `a` and `b` occur at the same time point,

`(A>C)` means that we have the single event `A>C` at the time point.

`(a)-(b)` denotes a sequence of length 2 where event `a` precedes event `b`.

## Update in response to Stephan's comment

Let's consider the following example

```
(seq <- seqdef('HHHAABBBAAGGG', stsep=''))
##     Sequence
## [1] H-H-H-A-A-B-B-B-A-A-G-G-G

seqecreate(seq, tevent='state')
## [1] (H)-3-(A)-2-(B)-3-(A)-2-(G)-3

seqecreate(seq, tevent='transition')
## [1] (H)-3-(H>A)-2-(A>B)-3-(B>A)-2-(A>G)-3
```

The state sequence has 5 spells, 2 in state `A` and 1 in each of the states `H`, `B`, and `G`. Now there are different possibilities to convert this state sequence into an event sequence. The `tevent='state'`and `tevent='transition'` are just two possibilities out of many.

Using `tevent='state'` we get an event sequence where the event `(A)` occurs twice because we have two spells in state `A`. Each of these two spells is initiated by the same event `(A)` that does not account for the preceding state.

Looking at the event sequence obtained with the `tevent='transition'` option,  we observe that the spells in `A` are here initiated by two different events `(H>A)` and `(B>A)` that account for the preceding state.

The first event sequence has two subsequences `(H)-(A)`, which correspond to the subsequences `(H)-(H>A)` and `(H)-(B>A)` in the second event sequence.

Comment: But how ist ist possible to have `(a)-(b)` without `(a>b)`?
In my case I have the subsequence `(H)-(A>G)` which is more frequent than (H)-(H>A)-(A>G) but how is the first one even possible without the second one also being true (`tevent=transition`)?

And what ist the difference between `(H)-(G)` in state notation and `(H>G)` in transition notation how can they not be the same?

Sorry for my confusion! And thanks for your clarification!

Comment: Subsequence is not a substring. A subsequence contains elements of the sequence in the same order as in the sequence, but that are not necessarily consecutive in the sequence. E.g., a-c is a subsequence of a-b-c. For the rest, see the update of my answer.